# Go modules cannot be updated on GoLand IDE

Tags: go, goland

I'm a beginner on golang. Every time I remove the `go 1.13`, it suddenly goes back again. I'm not sure why. It has something to do with GoLand?

```
module github.com/Projec/test

require (
    cloud.google.com/go v0.44.3
    github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go v3.2.0+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/gobuffalo/envy v1.7.1 // indirect
    github.com/helloeave/json v1.11.0
    github.com/labstack/echo v3.3.10+incompatible
    github.com/labstack/gommon v0.2.8 // indirect
    github.com/mailgun/mailgun-go/v3 v3.6.0
    github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.4 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.9 // indirect
    github.com/metakeule/fmtdate v1.1.2
    github.com/mileusna/useragent v0.0.0-20190129205925-3e331f0949a5
    github.com/murooka/go-diff-image v0.0.0-20171228143924-8c413ad9b24c
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.8.1
    github.com/sergi/go-diff v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/valyala/fasttemplate v1.0.1 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190829043050-9756ffdc2472
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20190827160401-ba9fcec4b297
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.2
    google.golang.org/api v0.9.0
    google.golang.org/appengine v1.6.2
)

go 1.13
```

Comment: Do not post images of text.

Comment: And no. This will reapear on every build and you cannot do anything against it and it   is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using Go 1.13 to develop your application.

In this case, whenever you run a Go command, like `go build`, `go list`, `go test`, `go mod tidy` and others, the `go.mod` file will be modified to have some formatting included, and add missing directives, like the Go version that's compatible with that module.

So, `go 1.13` is added to the file automatically, not by the IDE. You can reproduce this by running any of the commands that I listed above.

Comment: I see. So how I can down grade? I think I accidently updated the version from 1.11 to 1.13.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in this context. If you want to mark the minimal version for Go that's compatible with the module, then you can change the version from `go 1.13` to `go 1.11`. But that doesn't mean you can't use Go 1.15 to compile it (it should be 100% safe).

Comment: Oh i see. I'm a little confused since when I run the `go version` on my terminal, it says `go 1.11` but on my go.mod file its `go 1.13`. And when I try to remove the `go 1.13` on the go.mod file, it suddenly goes back again. I just want the `go 1.13` to be removed on the go.mod file.

Comment: What's the Go version you are using in the IDE? You can see it under Settings / Preferences | Go | GOROOT. If that's Go 1.13, then that's probably where the difference comes from. Replace `go 1.13` to `go 1.11`, and it should be ok.

Comment: I think that's what I'm trying to find. Thank you so much man!